# SQL Server: Infer historic monthly count from status change log

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope you can help. I have a list of status change dates and the status on that date for a table of objects. I need to be able to answer the question "how many were active in a given month"

Since this is the most complex SQL I have used previously I hope you don't mind me turning to this board for help. If I knew what I was searching for I could probably work it out for myself, so any pointers or a link would be appreciated.

This is where I am, and what the output looks like. Note this just works for "today" i.e. `Getdate()` but I'd like to replace "today" with all month ends form January 2011.

```
--Begin common table expression - determine fields being brought back CLD data
 with rankedValues (ConfirmedAmount, AccountNumber, PortfolioName, RankNumber, ProposalStatusName, StatusChangeDate, Determination) as
(
SELECT cld.ConfirmedAmount as Confirmed_Amount, cld.ProposalId as AccCount, blu.PortfolioName, 
-- Rank AND de-dupe
  Rank() over (partition by cld.AccountReference order by cld.owedamountid desc) as RankNumber, Pstat.ProposalStatusName, pstat.StatusChangeDate, det.Determination
  FROM [tixdata].[dbo].[CLD_201305] cld
  left outer join dbo.tblBookLookup blu on cld.BrandName = blu.BookName
  left outer join [tixdata].[dbo].[PD_201305] pstat on CLD.ProposalId = pstat.ProposalId
  left outer join dbo.DeterminationDateLookup det on cld.BrandName = det.Brand
    Where Cld.BrandName <> 'Sold/Putback'
    and cld.CurrentVersion = 1
    --Remove any BKX double-counting
    AND (cld.AccountReference not in (select distinct AccountNumber from BKX_201305))
 )

--Fuigure out what is actually !"Active"
Select RV.Range as [True Status], COUNT(AccountNumber) AccountCount, PortfolioName
 into #rv2

 From(Select Case
 When ProposalStatusName = 'Active' and GETDATE() > Determination then 'Active'
 When ProposalStatusName = 'Pending Chairmans' and GETDATE() > Determination then 'Active'
 When ProposalStatusName = 'Pending Review' and GETDATE() > Determination then 'Active'
 When ProposalStatusName = 'Broken' and GETDATE() >  Determination and GETDATE() < StatusChangeDate then 'Active'
 When ProposalStatusName = 'Closed' and GETDATE() > Determination and GETDATE() < StatusChangeDate then 'Active'
 Else 'Not_Active'
 End as range, ConfirmedAmount, AccountNumber, PortfolioName, ProposalStatusName,StatusChangeDate, Determination From rankedValues 
 where RankNumber = 1) RV
   Group by RV.Range, PortfolioName

--Consolidate
select * from #rv2 where [True Status] = 'Active'

drop table #rv2
```

Current Output:

```
True Status ¦ Account Count ¦ Portfolio Name
Active      ¦ 10000 ¦ P1
Active      ¦ 700   ¦ P2
Active      ¦ 2000  ¦ P5
```

Desired Output:

```
Month   ¦P1 ¦ P2    ¦P3
Jan 2011
Feb 2011
Mar 2011
.
.
.
Jun 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table of months (physically or constructed) you could do a cross join:

```
select 
  case when r.date < m.month then 'a' else 'b' end
from baseresults r
cross join months m
where m.month < GETDATE()
```

To get the portfolio from rows to columns you would have to use PIVOT ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)